# Subtrees of a tree

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, recursive-algorithms

I have a given tree with n nodes. The task is to find the number of subtrees of the given tree with outgoing edges to its complement less than or equal to a given number K.

for example: If `n=3` and `k=1`

and the given tree is    `1---2---3`

Then the total valid subtrees would be 6

```
{}, {1}, {3}, {1,2}, {2,3}, {1,2,3}
```

I know I can enumerate all `2^n` trees and chack the valid ones, but is there some approach that is faster? Can I achieve polynomial time in `n`? Something close to `O(n^3)` or even `O(n^4)` would be nice.

for k=1 this value turns out to be `2*n`

Here is a link to the 
[problem statement](http://www.spoj.com/problems/CNTTREE/)

Comment: This is part of the [HackerRank contest](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/may13/challenges/cutTree). Wait for the end of the competition if you don't know the answer.

Comment: I have locked this question since it is part of an ongoing contest. Note that the problem statement linked to in the question disagrees with the content of the question (in particular gives a different answer for this example) while the HackerRank problem statement gives this example.